# How to scrape Google URLs with Xpath (Contains and not contains)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I want to get the urls from google results.

This xpath works perfectly BUT there is a problem:

```
//div[@class='r']/a
```

Google shows some results from featured snippets and People Also Ask (https://www.google.com/search?q=people+also+ask+example) and that xpath gets all those url results.

I realized there is a parent div with "g" class, and only the People Also Ask div has the class "kno-kp".

So the solution is easy:

Select every div class that contains "g" and not contains "kno-kp"

[image: google results]

This is my xpath but it doesn't work:

```
//div[contains(@class,'g') and not(contains(@class,'kno-kp'))]//div[@class='r']/a
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `//div[@class='g']//div[@class='r']/a` only this xpath gave me 8 matching urls

Comment: Do you want the URLs that does't contains 'People Also Ask'? I have accessed the [URL](https://www.google.com/search?q=people+also+ask+example) from India and the div with class 'g' does't contain 'kno-kp' at all.

Comment: @AlexGüemez What was this url `https://www.google.com/search?q=people+also+ask+example` all about?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should fix your problem:

```
//div[@class='r'][count(ancestor::*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' g ')])=1]
```

Useful info about xpath above: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1390680/14187083)