# XPath check if div contains a substring

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I need to find every HTML div which class starts with `mod mod-article-tile mod-article-tile--tertiary`. I found various explanations for XPath Contains, and can't seem to figure it out. Here is an example:
My code that finds only the divs with this exact class (tested and works): `'//*[@class="mod mod-article-tile mod-article-tile--tertiary"]/@id'`

What I think was my closest guess: `'//*contains(@class, "mod mod-article-tile mod-article-tile--tertiary")/@id'`

If anyone could explain why it doesn't work and how I can fix it, that'd be great. XPath is still pretty confusing with the whole symbol syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to put the contains() in a predicate ([ ])...

```xml
//*[contains(@class, "mod mod-article-tile mod-article-tile--tertiary")]/@id
```

Note though that those classes will still need to appear in that order to match. See the [answers in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390568/how-can-i-match-on-an-attribute-that-contains-a-certain-string) for more info/help.